# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx =-\frac{\pi^2 \sqrt{2}}{16}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I could prove it using the residues but I'm interested to have it in a different way (for example using Gamma/Beta or any other functions) to show that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x^{4} + 1}\,{\rm d}x
=-\frac{\,\pi^{2}\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,}{16}.
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both answers look greater than each other :), but I would like to wait for while before selecting one.

Comment: Thank you OL and tetori for your nice answers and great support. I will have to choose the 1st answer but both were really amazing.

Comment: Consider [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral/290400#290400).

Comment: For example: Beta Function, PolyLogarithms, etc$\ldots$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possible way is to introduce
$$ I(s)=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^{s-\frac34}dy}{1+y}.\tag{1}$$
The integral you are looking for is obtained as $I'(0)$ after the change of variables $y=x^4$.

Let us make in (1) another change of variables: $\displaystyle t=\frac{y}{1+y}\Longleftrightarrow y=\frac{t}{1-t},dy=\frac{dt}{(1-t)^2}$. This gives
\begin{align}
I(s)&=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1t\cdot\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{s-\frac74}\cdot \frac{dt}{(1-t)^2}=\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1t^{s-\frac34}(1-t)^{-s-\frac{1}{4}}dt=\\&
=\frac{1}{16}B\left(s+\frac14,-s+\frac34\right)=\\&
=\frac{1}{16}\Gamma\left(s+\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(-s+\frac34\right)=\\
&=\frac{\pi}{16\sin\pi\left(s+\frac14\right)}.
\end{align}
Differentiating this with respect to $s$, we indeed get
$$I'(0)=-\frac{\pi^2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}{16\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}}=-\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{2}}{16}.$$

Comment: O.L. rulez .. (+1)

Comment: Where did you learn all your cool tricks, O.L.? (I know this particular one is standard, but I'm speaking more generally.) Also, do you happen to have a background in physics or applied stuff (just curious -- it seems to me that physicists are always very good with these kinds of things.)

Comment: Practice, practice and more practice. Learn the definition of special functions, dilogarithm, polygamma, beta, gamma, LambertW and learn the transformations. Each integral is a mix between experience and trial and error.

Comment: @Potato Thanks, I am very pleased. Indeed I have partly physics background, but I think some working complex-analysis experience is more relevant here.

Comment: I think this trick needs some justification. Why differentiation inside the integral sign is legit here, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, we can split the denominator part as follows
$$
\frac{1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-i}-\frac{1}{x^2+i}\right).
$$
Consequently, the integral becomes
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx =\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2-i}-\frac{\ln x}{x^2+i}\right)\ dx.
$$
Using formula from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral?lq=1),
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}\ dx=\frac {\pi \ln a}{2a},
$$
we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac {\pi \ln \sqrt{-i}}{2\sqrt{-i}}-\frac {\pi \ln \sqrt{i}}{2\sqrt{i}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4i}\left(\frac {\ln i^{\frac{3}{2}}}{i^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac {\ln i^{\frac{1}{2}}}{i^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Taking $0\le\theta\le2\pi$, from Euler's formula we have
$$
e^\frac{i\pi}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=i.
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx
&=\frac{\pi}{4i}\left(\frac {\ln e^\frac{3i\pi}{4}}{e^\frac{3i\pi}{4}}-\frac {\ln e^\frac{i\pi}{4}}{e^\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4i}\left(-\frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\color{blue}{-\Large\frac{\pi^2}{16}\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}
$$
$$\\$$

---

$$\large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
     =-\,{\pi^2 \root{2} \over 16}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\overbrace{\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x}}
> ^{\ds{x^{4} \mapsto x}}
> ={1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/4}\ln\pars{x} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over 16}\lim_{\mu \to -3/4}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\mu} \over x + 1}\,\dd x 
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}\lim_{\mu \to -3/4}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{x + 1}t}\,\dd t\,\dd x 
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}\lim_{\mu \to -3/4}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}\lim_{\mu \to -3/4}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-\mu - 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> \pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-t}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}\lim_{\mu \to -3/4}
> \partiald{\bracks{\Gamma\pars{-\mu}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}}{\mu} 
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$.

Whith [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm)
${\bf\mbox{6.1.17}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x}
={1 \over 16}\,\left.
\partiald{\bracks{\pi\csc\pars{-\pi\mu}}}{\mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ -3/4}
={1 \over 16}\,
\bracks{\pi^{2}\cot\pars{3\pi \over 4}\csc\pars{3\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
> =-\,{\root{2} \over 16}\,\pi^2}
> $$

Comment: The ghost $\partial_u$!

Comment: @Integrals It's quite useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $t=1/(1+x^4)$ then we get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx =\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)(1-t)^{-3/4}t^{-1/4}dt.$$
And $\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)/\Gamma(x+y)$, we get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\mathrm{B}(x,y)[\psi(x)-\psi(x+y)]$$
where $\psi$ is [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). And by Euler integral of the first kind we get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\int_0^1 \ln t\cdot t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt.$$
So
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
&&\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)(1-t)^{-3/4}t^{-1/4}dt  \\ &=&\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln(1-t) (1-t)^{-3/4} t^{-1/4}dt-\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln(t)\cdot (1-t)^{-3/4} t^{-1/4}dt\\
&=& \frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln (t)\cdot t^{-3/4} (1-t)^{-1/4}dt -\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \ln(t)\cdot (1-t)^{-3/4} t^{-1/4}dt\\
&=&\frac{1}{16}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi(1)\right]-\frac{1}{16}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)\left[\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi(1)\right] \\
&=&\frac{1}{16}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \right]
\end{array}
$$
And $\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \right]=-\pi^2\sqrt{2}$. (It can easily be derived from reflection formula of [gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) and [digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) function.)

Answer (score 4):

And yet another way for you to enjoy. Define

$$f(z):=\frac{\text{Log}\,z}{z^4+1}\;,\;\;C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;z=Re^{it}\,,\,\,0<t<\pi\}\;,\;\;1<R\in\Bbb R$$

Now, the only poles within the region determined by $\,C_R\,$ are the simple (why? And note that $\,z=0\,$ is a pole but with residue equal to zero...) ones

$$z_1=e^{\frac{\pi i}4}\;,\;\;z_2=e^{\frac{3\pi i}4}\implies$$

$$\begin{align*}\text{Res}_{z=z_1}(f)&=\lim_{z\to z_1}(z-z_1)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to z_1}\frac{\text{Log}\,z}{4z^3}&=\frac{\pi i}{16e^{\frac{3\pi i}4}}&=\frac{\pi }{16\sqrt2}\left(1-i\right)=\\
\text{Res}_{z=z_2}(f)&=\lim_{z\to z_2}(z-z_2)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to z_2}\frac{\text{Log}\,z}{4z^3}&=\frac{3\pi i}{16e^{\frac{\pi i}4}}&=\frac{3\pi }{16\sqrt2}\left(1+i\right)\end{align*}$$

So by Cauchy Theorem we get:

$$2\pi i\left(\frac{\pi}{16\sqrt2}\left(1-i\right)+\frac{3\pi}{16\sqrt2}\left(1+i\right)\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt2}=\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{dx}{x^4+1}+\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz$$

And since

$$\left|\;\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz\;\right|\le\frac{\pi R}{R^4-1}\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

we get

$$2\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^4+1}\stackrel{\text{why?}}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^4+1}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt2}$$

**Note:** To do the above we *had* to choose a branch cut for the complex logarithm function, yet we didn't choose the usual one (i.e., the non-positive reals) but rather the negative purely imaginary axis, so...**why can we do that?**, and what happened with zero, the great nemesis of the complex logarithm?

Comment: I thought OP doesn't want complex-analytic methods. If I were to find this integral by residues, I would simply write $$\int=\frac12\mathrm{Re}\int_{\mathbb{R}+i0}\frac{\ln x\,dx}{1+x^4}=\mathrm{Re}\left\{\pi i\left(\mathrm{res}_{x=e^{i\pi/4}}+\mathrm{res}_{x=e^{3i\pi/4}}\right)\frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}\right\}.$$

Comment: Yes I know.,yet the complex approach is interesting, imo, because of the logarithm. Anyway, it is just another approach.

Comment: Thanks again friends, but I'm curious to know how you usually solve problems using residues without plotting them! It seems I need to practice a lot (It took me several pages lol).

Comment: What do you mean "plotting them [the residues, I presume]"? I didn't *plot* anything, I just calculated the residues at the poles contained within the region enclosed by the closed path...

Comment: DonAntonio: Could you explain why the singularity at z=0 for the complex logarithm is ignored in your solution? Thanks.

Comment: It is not igonored, @user70520. As I wrote there, it is singularity with residue zero since $$\lim_{z\to 0}\,z\,f(z)=z\,\text{Log}\,(z)\frac1{z^4+1}=0\cdot 1=0$$

Comment: If the residue at z=0 is 0, does that mean the singularity z=0 isn't a pole?

Answer (score 3):

We can use the following way to solve. It is very simple. In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}dx-\int_0^1 \frac{x^2\ln x}{1+x^4}dx\tag{1}\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(x^{4n}-x^{4n+2})\ln xdx\tag{2}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}\\
&=&-\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{16}\tag{3}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here, for (1), (2), and (3), we used the substitute $x\to\frac{1}{x}$, $\int_0^1x^n\ln xdx=-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$, and
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{(an+b)^2}=\frac{\pi^2a^2\cos\frac{b\pi}{a}}{\sin^2\frac{b\pi}{a}} $$
respectively.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you add extra explanations such as in the $2$nd line you use substitution $x\mapsto\frac1x$ and the $4$th line you use
[$$
\int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}, \qquad\text{for }\  n=0,1,2,\ldots
$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/877844/123277)
+1 anyway.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, thanks. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac {\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx
=&\int_0^1 \frac {(1-x^2)\ln x}{x^4+1}\ dx\\
\overset{ibp}=&-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^1\frac1x 
\ln\frac{x^2+\sqrt2 x+1}{x^2-\sqrt2 x+1}dx\\
=&-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^1\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 
\frac{2\cos y}{x^2+2x\sin y+1}dy \ dx\\
 =&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \left(\frac\pi4-\frac y2\right) dy=-\frac{\pi^2 }{8\sqrt2}
\end{align}