# Residue of $e^x x^{-r-1} \log x$ at $x=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If it exists, what is the residue of $e^x x^{-r-1} \log x$ at $x=0$?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: $x=0$ is not an isolated singularity in this case, so we can't talk about residue.

Comment: Thanks! What I was trying to do was to calculate the Cauchy integral $\oint_{|x|=1} e^x x^{-r-1} \log x dx$. I was asking myself whether that could be calculated using the Residue theorem. But as I see, the answer is no.

Comment: for assigning a residue to a branch point, you have to consider something like a Bromwich contour

Comment: @Matthias of course you can't use the residue theorem, $e^x x^{-r-1} \log x$ is not holomorphic on $|x| = 1$ (it is not even continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned it's not isolated...

i suggest to read this:

[Type of singularity of $\log z$ at $z=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458511/type-of-singularity-of-log-z-at-z-0)