# What can be said about the pole of the logarithmic function at zero? Does it have an order?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

It seems the pole of the logarithmic function is special. Can we assign an order to this pole? Is it a pole of zeroth order?

Comment: The logarithm cannot even be *defined* as an analytic function in a (punctured) neighborhood of $z=0$. Please clarify the question.

Comment: It is not a pole, it is a branch point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of singularity of $\log z$ at $z=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458511/type-of-singularity-of-log-z-at-z-0)