# Seemingly hard integrals which are made easy via differentiation under the integral sign a.k.a Feynman Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, big-list

I recently discovered [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) a.k.a Feynman Integration and I read an [article](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf) which says it can be substituted for contour integration. Therefore, I am assuming this technique is, indeed, very powerful. I was looking for a list of integrals which are, seemingly, hard but are made easy via this technique.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One of them is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874029/a-binet-like-integral-int-01-left-frac1-ln-x-frac11-x-frac/874155#874155

Comment: Some easier examples of such integrals are
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^4}dx$$
and
$$\int^1_0x^a(\ln{x})^bdx$$

Comment: Wikipedia gives a dozen of examples of different types. You don't find this sufficient?

Comment: @O.L. I thought it would be nice to have a list on math.se with explanations provided by experienced users to look at and furthermore, for people new to the technique to look it's power and see how it applies to a wide range of integrals.

Comment: You should certainly look at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf for some nice insights by Keith Conrad

Answer (score 7):

Note that
$$
\int_0^1 x^\alpha\ dx=\frac1{\alpha+1},\qquad\text{for }\ \alpha>-1.\tag1
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ $n$ times yields
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^n}{\partial\alpha^n}\left(x^\alpha\right)\ dx=\color{blue}{\int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}}, \qquad\text{for }\  n=0,1,2,\ldots\tag2
$$