# evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^4+1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have no idea how to even go about this one. I tried to set $z^4+1 = 0$ and I don't even know if my answers are correct. Someone help please!!!

Comment: Try integrating around the boundary of {z \in \C : 0 <= Arg(z) <= \pi/2 and r <= |z| <= R} as r->0 and R->\infty. I haven't done it myself but that looks promising. Also, wolfram alpha says the answer is -\pi^2/(8 \sqrt(2)), so check your answer with that.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral).

Comment: I'm mainly having issues with this problem because I don't know what to do in the denominator. I usually have x^2 + 1 now the exponent is 4 and nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using $\gamma=[0,R]\cup Re^{i\frac\pi2[0,1]}\cup i[R,0]$ as $R\to\infty$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{\log(z)}{z^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x-i\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac\pi2i+\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x-i\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
There is one singularity at $e^{i\pi/4}$ inside $\gamma$:
$$
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{i\pi/4}}\frac{\log(z)}{z^4+1}
=\frac{i\pi/4}{4e^{i3\pi/4}}
=\frac\pi{16\sqrt2}(1-i)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x-i\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\pi i\frac\pi{16\sqrt2}(1-i)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}(1+i)
\end{align}
$$
Which gives us not only
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}
$$
but also
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

> *I have no idea how to even go about this one.*

Notice that if $~I(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{^{a-1}}}{x^n+1}dx,~$ then $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^n+1}dx=I'(1).~$ But $I(a)$ can be shown

to equal $\dfrac\pi n\cdot\csc\bigg(a\cdot\dfrac\pi n\bigg)$ by first letting $t=\dfrac1{x^n+1}$ , then recognizing the expression of the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

[function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and lastly applying [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to the new result. Now all that's left to do is to differentiate the expression with regards to *a*, then replace

*a* with $1$ and *n* with $4$. The final result should be $-\bigg(\dfrac\pi n\bigg)^2\cdot\csc\bigg(a\cdot\dfrac\pi n\bigg)\cdot\cot\bigg(a\cdot\dfrac\pi n\bigg)$, which in our case becomes $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}$ .

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), simply using contour integration, it is shown that $$\frac{\pi}{m}\csc\left(\pi\frac{n+1}{m}\right) =\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ This is also a valid approach (+1).