# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx$$
I don't know where to start with this so either the full evaluation or any hints or pushes in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral).

Comment: @ Tunk-Fey A question formulated like this lacks context and it shows no own effort. According to the rules of this forum  it should have been closed instead of being edited by the moderation.

Comment: Oh, this was a question in my Calculus exam... It brought back good/bad memories :D

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Hint**

Write $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(1+x^2)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{(1+x^2)}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(1+x^2)}dx$$ For the second integral make a change of variable $x=\frac{1}{y}$ and see the beauty of the result.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: This is true elegance, sir!

Comment: woops!! I almost forgot this method (+1)

Comment: @orion. I really appreciate your comment ! What I learnt is that simple is beautiful and vice-versa. And don't forget how old I am ! Cheers.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha. Nice but don't you think that, by the end, we are doing exactly the same thing ? I should enjoy a discussion with you on this topic. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I suddenly feel sportive and decided to add another method. By the way, I saw this problem first on Integration Bee on MIT.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha. Your answer is very nice and be sure I appreciate it. But I am serious when I ask for your opinion on the question : are we or not doing the same ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yep!! we are just a little different approach :) cheers!!

Comment: Sir Claude's always Sir Claude :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Long time no speak ! By the way, what do you mean ? Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: it was just a way to appreciate your elegance :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio.This is really nice ! Thank you very much.

Comment: @claude leibovici: thanks for pointing that mistake +1

Comment: @OlivierOloa. Many thanks for your kind words but don't kidd the old man !

Comment: Is there an exact numerical value for $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$

Comment: @mike. $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=-C$ where $C$ is Catalan constant. $(C \sim 0.915966)$.

Answer (score 52):

In general
$$
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+\alpha^2}\ dx
$$
can be evaluated by using substitution $u=\dfrac{\alpha^2}{x}\;\Rightarrow\;x=\dfrac{\alpha^2}{u}\;\Rightarrow\;dx=-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{u^2}\ du$, then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln \left(\dfrac{\alpha^2}{u}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{\alpha^2}{u}\right)^2+\alpha^2}\cdot \dfrac{\alpha^2}{u^2}\ du\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\ln \alpha-\ln u}{\alpha^2+u^2}\ du\\
&=2\ln \alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\alpha^2+u^2}\ du-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln u}{u^2+\alpha^2}\ du\\
&=2\ln \alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\alpha^2+u^2}\ du-\mathcal{I}(\alpha)\\
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)&=\ln \alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\alpha^2+u^2}\ du.
\end{align}
The last integral can easily be evaluated since it is a common integral. Using substitution $u=\tan\theta$, the integral turns out to be
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)&=\frac{\ln \alpha}{\alpha}\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2} \ d\theta\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{\pi\ln \alpha}{2\alpha}}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\mathcal{I}(1)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\ dx=\large\color{blue}{0}.
$$

Comment: +1 for generalizing the result, and for your nice typesetting skills :)

Comment: @DavidH Thanks... :)

Comment: @Tunk-Fey. This is very elegant. Thanks for this nice answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks Sir. Yours is also elegant... :)

Comment: An easier substitution would have been $x \mapsto au$, with the same points as above =)

Answer (score 35):

Here's another very short solution.

The substitution $x \to e^t$ transforms the integral to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t+e^{-t}}\,dt$$

which is zero by the anti-symmetry of the integrand.

Comment: I think the only reason this answer has less upvotes is because it was late to the game... this is very slick!!!!

Comment: @ coreyman317 Thanks for your remark. The voting scheme sometimes produces peculiar results, so it should not be takes too seriously.

Comment: such a nice solution(+1)

Answer (score 29):

Here is one appraoch!!

changing $x = \tan \theta$ 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\log(\tan\theta)}{\sec^2 \theta} \sec^2 \theta d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\sin \theta) d\theta - \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \log (\cos \theta) d\theta $$

By changing $\theta \to \pi/2 - \theta$ on the latter integrand, we get
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\sin \theta) d\theta - \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \log (\cos (\pi/2-\theta)) d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\sin \theta) d\theta - \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \log (\sin \theta) d\theta = 0$$

Answer (score 18):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\color{#66f}{\Large I}\equiv\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{x \mapsto {1 \over x}}}\ =\
\int_{\infty}^{0}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over 1 + \pars{1/x}^{2}}
\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x=\color{#66f}{\Large -I}
$$

> $$
> \imp\ \color{#66f}{\Large I} + \color{#66f}{\Large I}=0\ \imp\
> \color{#66f}{\Large I\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
> =\color{#c00000}{0}}
> $$

Answer (score 13):

Here's another general result, consider for $|a|\le 1$:

\begin{align*}
  I(a,b) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{x^a}{b^2+x^2}\, dx \\
  &= \frac{b^{a-1}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{t^{(a-1)/2}}{1+t}\, dt \tag{1}\\
  &= \frac{b^{a-1}}{2}\, \mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1+a}{2},\frac{1-a}{2}\right) \tag 2\\
  &= \frac{b^{a-1}}{2}\, \frac{\pi}{\displaystyle \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}} \tag 3
\end{align*}
$(1)$ is by subst. $\displaystyle x=b\sqrt{t}$

$(2)$ is by the definition of Beta function: $\displaystyle \mathrm{B}(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}} \, dx$

$(3)$ is by using $\displaystyle \mathrm{B}(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma{(a)}\Gamma{(b)}}{\Gamma{(a+b)}}$ and Euler's reflection formula $\displaystyle \Gamma{(a)}\Gamma{(1-a)}=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\displaystyle \left({\pi}\, a\right)}}$

Hence,

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{x^a \left(\log{x}\right)^n}{b^2+x^2}\, dx &= \frac{\partial^{n} }{\partial a^n} \left(\frac{b^{a-1}}{2}\, \frac{\pi}{\cos{\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}}\right)
\end{align*}
and when $b=1, n=1, a= 0$, the result is $0$

**Update:**

An even better result:

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \frac{x^a \left(\log{x}\right)^n}{b^c+x^c}\, dx &= \frac{\partial^{n} }{\partial a^n} \left(\frac{b^{a+1-c}}{c}\, \frac{\pi}{\sin{\displaystyle \left(\frac{1+a}{c}\pi\right)}}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\displaystyle 0<\frac{1+a}{c}<1$

Comment: How did you get the value of the integral after "hence"? Where $\log^n$ was added

Comment: @TylerHG : By differentiating $I(a,b)$ with respect to $a$ $n$ times.

Answer (score 8):

**Another general approach :**

Consider
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{b-1}}{a^2+x^2}\ dx.\tag1
$$
Rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{b-1}}{a^2+x^2}\ dx&=\frac1{a^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{b-1}}{1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}\ dx.\tag2
\end{align}
Putting $x=ay\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;dx=a\ dy$ yields
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{b-1}}{a^2+x^2}\ dx&=a^{b-2}\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{b-1}}{1+y^2}\ dy,
\end{align}
where
[\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{b-1}}{1+y^2}\ dy=\frac{\pi}{2\sin\left(\frac{b\pi}{2}\right)}.
\end{align}](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816036/123277)
Hence
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{b-1}}{a^2+x^2}\ dx&=\frac\pi2\cdot\frac{a^{b-2}}{\sin\left(\frac{b\pi}{2}\right)}.\tag3
\end{align}
Differentiating $(3)$ with respect to $b$ and setting $b=1$ yields
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left[\frac{x^{b-1}}{a^2+x^2}\right]_{b=1}\ dx&=\frac\pi2\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left[\frac{a^{b-2}}{\sin\left(\frac{b\pi}{2}\right)}\right]_{b=1}\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}\ dx&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{\pi\ln a}{2a}}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\ dx=\large\color{blue}{0}.
$$

Comment: Nice, is there a close form of $I=\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx=-\int_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx$ ?

Comment: I have just tried Mathematica and it gave: $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, dx=-catalan$, it is a constant defined on wikpedia:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant

Comment: Try to combine answers?