# Show that $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^{p - 1}\ln\left(x\right)}{1 + x}\,{\rm d}x=-\pi^{2}\csc\left(p\pi\right)\cot\left(p\pi\right)$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$
> \mbox{Show that}\quad
> \int^{\infty}_{0}{x^{p - 1}\ln\left(x\right) \over 1 + x}
> =-\pi^{2}\csc\left(p\pi\right)\cot\left(p\pi\right)
> $$

$$
\mbox{I guess I have to use the fact that}\quad
\int^{\infty}_{0}{x^{p - 1} \over 1 + x}
=\pi\csc\left(p\pi\right),\quad\mbox{please give me some idea.}
$$

> Thank you.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $p$.

Comment: It must be a minus to get this result. I was typing almost the same comment when your came ! You won ! Cheers  :-)

Comment: You can use [Mellin transform technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral/290400#290400).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lest the question remain unanswered:

We have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{p-1}\ln x}{1+x}\,dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dp}\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x}\,dx = \frac{d}{dp} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x}\,dx$$

for $0 < p < 1$, since the dominated convergence theorem guarantees that differentiation under the integral is legitimate.

And

$$\frac{d}{dp} \frac{\pi}{\sin (p\pi)} = - \frac{\pi^2\cos (p\pi)}{\sin^2 (p\pi)} = -\pi^2\csc (p\pi)\cot (p\pi).$$

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but how did you get from $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x}\,dx$ to $\frac{\pi}{\sin (p\pi)}$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw That was given in the question as a fact, so I took that as known. One can get that for example by the residue theorem, or by transforming it into a form one recognises as an integral representation of the beta function, specifically $B(p,1-p)$.