# How to show this integral equals $\pi^2$?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I was trying to evaluate an integral related to the product of two cauchy distributions and in one of the steps got stuck in the integral

> $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} dx. $$

I tried to evaluate the integral using Mathematica, and it seems that the answer is $\pi^2$. Furthermore, if I restrict the integral to $(0,1)$, the answer is just $\pi^2/2$, i.e. the integral over $(0,1)$ and the integral over $(1,\infty)$ are equal. 
I was wondering if anyone could help me verify/disprove this identity? I apologize in advance if this seems an ill-posed question.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your second question falls in the scope of MSE either, but it definitely represents a separate question (advice / soft-question etc. versus integration.)

Comment: The integral does indeed equal the square of pi, as I remember seeing this specific one some time ago.

Comment: @Semiclassical I will edit the question, but it remains a curiosity .. If one could use Mathematica outputs, hours would have been saved, but I personally don't trust Mathematica that much.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to work this out by setting $x=u^{-1}$, but without using polylogarithm functions(if we're allowed to use them, the substitution is useless anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution $\sqrt{x}=t$ which gives $$4\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\log(t)}{t^{2}-1}dt}$$
Notice the symmetry at $t=1$, or if you prefer spliting up the integral and making the change of Variable $t=\frac{1}{u}$ at $(1,\infty]$

This reduces to $$8\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\log(u)}{u^{2}-1}du}$$

Expanding the denomenator into a geometric series and applying the monotone convergence theorem we get that $$-8\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\log(u)}{1-u^{2}}du}=-8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{u^{2n}\log(u)du}=8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}}$$

The later sum is well-known to evaluate at $\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}$

Comment: I just wrote essentially the same solution just a few minutes ago :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that! Since you where a few minutes earlier than me I gave you a thumbs up! :)

Comment: You guys are seriously awesome! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral).

We will use the Mellin transform approach

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx \implies F'(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x)dx.  $$

So the whole problem boils down to find the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{x-1} $ which is given by

> $$ F(s) = (-1)^{s+1}\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) , $$

where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function. Differentiating $F(s)$ and taking the limit as $s$ goes to $1/2$  gives the desired result

> $$ I = \pi^2 $$

Comment: +1 A very nice, brief solution. The Mellin transform is very powerful.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Gahawar: Thank you for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @VitalStatistix: You are very welcome.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x)dx$. The RHS has an extra $\ln(x)$. I do not understand this formula.

Comment: @mike: We just differentiate with respect to $s$. You know the derivative of $x^{s-1}$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal. Thanks for the quick reply.  But I am still not getting it.  You meant that your first equation is: $F(s) = \color{red}{\frac{d}{ds}}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x)dx.$?

Comment: @mike: Yes, because we want to generate the $\ln(x)$ under the integral sign. See the original integral and the links.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal.  I think that your first equation line should go like this: $F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx; \color{red}{\frac{d}{ds}F(s)}= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x)dx$. please double check.

Comment: @mike: I fixed it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Now it is correct. thanks!

Comment: @mike: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Another (low-tech) way to prove your claim is to consider that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2-1}\,dx =4\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x^2-1}\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2-1}\,dx \right)\\&=&8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log x}{1-x^2}\,dx=8\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)\,x^{2k}\,dx=8\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\\&=&8\left(\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)\right)=8\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\color{red}{\pi^2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: +1 I suppose that one can justify the swapping of integral and summation since the integrand is always greater than zero.

Answer (score 5):

Letting $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{\ln^{2}z}{\sqrt{z} (z-1)} $ and integrating around a keyhole contour where the branch cut is along the positive real axis, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{2} x}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} \ dx + \text{PV} \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{(\ln x + 2 \pi i )^{2}}{\sqrt{x e^{2 \pi i}}(x-1)} \ dx - i \pi \ \text{Res} [f(z), e^{2 \pi i}] =0  $$

where

$$ \text{Res}[f(z), e^{2 \pi i}]= \lim_{z \to e^{2 \pi i}} \frac{\ln^{2}z}{\sqrt{z}} = 4 \pi^{2} .$$

Equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, $$ 4 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} \ dx -  4 \pi^{3} = 0$$

or $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} \ dx = \pi^{2}.$$

**EDIT**:

Because of the $\sqrt{z}$ in the denominator, integrating $ \displaystyle g(z) = \frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{z}(z-1)}$ around the same contour would work as well.

Specifically, $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} \ dx + \text{PV} \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{\ln x + 2 \pi i }{\sqrt{x e^{2 \pi i}}(x-1)} \ dx - i \pi \ \text{Res} [g(z), e^{2 \pi i}] =0$$ where $$\text{Res}[g(z),2 \pi i] = -2 \pi i .$$

Equating the real parts on both sides of the equation, $$2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x} (x-1)} \ dx - 2 \pi^{2} = 0 $$

or $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(1-x)} \ dx = \pi^{2}. $$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{x}\pars{x - 1}}\,\dd x}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\Large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{x}\pars{x - 1}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{x}\pars{x - 1}}\,\dd x
> +\int_{1}^{0}{\root{x}\ln\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x - 1}}
> \,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{x}\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
> =-2\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu - 1/2} - x^{-1/2}
> \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> -\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1/2}}{\mu}
> =2\,\Psi'\pars{\half}=2\,{\pi^{2} \over 2} = \color{#66f}{\LARGE \pi^{2}}
> \approx {\tt 9.8696}
> \end{align}

Comment: You may also use dilog function to solve the integral. +1 anyway. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Awesome solution.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey It's true but I feel this way is a straightforward one. Thanks.

Comment: @UserX Thanks. It's nice it was useful for you.

Comment: @FelixMarin Do you think this integral has a closed-form?
$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(ax)}{1+2x}\ dx$$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I don't know yet. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey The "$a$" and the "$2$" are bad friends. There are many integrals in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406401v1.pdf) I don't see how to relate to this one.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes, I think so. I'm struggling to crack this integral for hours, yet no success so far. Thanks for the paper

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account the fact that you already received very good answers, I give here just as a curiosity (given by a CAS), $$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} dx=-2 \text{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)-2 \text{Li}_2\left(-\sqrt{x}\right)-\log
   \left(\sqrt{x}+1\right) \log (x)$$ $$\int_0^a \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}(x-1)} dx=\sqrt{a} \left(a \Phi \left(a,2,\frac{3}{2}\right)+4\right)-2 \log (a) \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)$$ and, if $a=1$, the result you already found $\frac{\pi ^2}{2}$ and the remaining coming from what Felix Marin shows at the beginning of his answer.