# How to calculate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

> How does one go about calculating :
>
> $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$$

*I've tried Integration by parts, and failed over and over again*

Comment: Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170331/why-is-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x1x2-mathrmdx-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\color{#C00000}{\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx}+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

---

**Let's find out :**

$$\color{#C00000}{\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx}$$

Subsitute : $$t=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\int_{\infty}^{1}\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{t})}{1+(\frac{1}{t})^2}\cdot-\frac{1}{t^2}dt=-\int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{\ln (t^{-1})}{t^2+1} dt=\int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{\ln (t)}{t^2+1} dt$$

> **Note:** $$\color{blue}{\int_a^b f(t) dt= -\int_b^a f(t) dt}$$

$$\int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt=-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt$$

---

**Back to**

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\color{#C00000}{\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx}+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\color{green}{-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx}$$

> Im sure you  can see that $x$ and $t$ are just to letters assigned to the integral **, that:**
>
> $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Therefore:

$$-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=0$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\color{green}{-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t)}{1+t^2} dt+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx}=0$$

Comment: Indeed, the principal value (**p.v**) is zero, right ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Just write $$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$ For the second integral, change variable $x=\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: @Antony. May I confess that I **hate** $\ln$ ? Thanks for the edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: mutual feeling bro. there's only one logarithm. :D

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis. Nice to know it, .... nipote ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Are you saying you hate the function, or the notation?

Comment: @columbus8myhw. The notation only ! The function is just pure beauty. As asaid by Gennaro Marco Devincenzis, there is (for me) only one logarithm. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What's wrong with it? It's fewer letters, and it's unambiguous. If you just write $\log$, it could be mistaken for the binary logarithm or common logarithm, both of which often being written as $\log$. (The binary logarithm is used quite often.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw. In mathematics house are many mansions ! I personally prefer $\log_a(x)$ if $a\neq e$ and $\log(x)$ otherwise. Just a question of taste. Cheers.